# SSRS 2016 Report Viewer V13 Toolbar Icons not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

When i was looking solution for the problem, i saw a [topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60fefd0f-2dd7-4813-afca-cf5cc6be8e8d/ssrs-2016-report-viewer-v13-toolbar-icons-not-displaying?forum=sqlreportingservices) on microsoft forums. The same question is asked by a user and i want to quote that question:

> The Report Viewer control is not rendering the toolbar correctly.
>
> I'm following the instruction Getting started with the ReportViewer
>   2016 control at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt764770.aspx
>   and am able to run reports from my application, however there are
>   issues with the Report Toolbar.
>
> 1. I'm not seeing the toolbar icons, even though the hyperlinks are active.
> 2. When I open the Export dropdown the background is transparent and difficult to read.
> 3. Report parameter dropdowns appear as textboxes, yet when I click them they act like dropdowns.
>
> Attached is an image showing the toolbar as it is rendering in my
>   application:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the control in a master/child page? There is a known issue with the current Report Viewer Control RC - https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/blob/master/Docs/Get-Started-With-RVC.md#known-issues

Comment: Yes, i was using the control in master page because my report page is strictly dependent on master page so i restored my sql server to version 2014 and report viewer to version 10.0.0.0 again.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can see this is still an issue, Microsoft still haven't released an update to correct the missing icons when using a Master/Child Page.

I got the control working in a normal ASPX page and took a look at how the icons were being displayed, it looks like a in-line style tag is generated per control instance.

As a temporary work around until Microsoft release a fix for this you can use the style tag below, i pulled this from the in-line css.

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: "reportingservicesglyphs-regular";
        src: url("/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=13.0.1700.305&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Fonts.ReportingServicesGlyphs.eot");
        src: url("/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=13.0.1700.305&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Fonts.ReportingServicesGlyphs.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=13.0.1700.305&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Fonts.ReportingServicesGlyphs.woff") format("woff"),url("/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=13.0.1700.305&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Fonts.ReportingServicesGlyphs.ttf") format("truetype"),url("/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=13.0.1700.305&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Fonts.ReportingServicesGlyphssvg#PowerBIGlyphs-regular") format("svg");
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
    }

    .glyphui {
        position: relative;
        top: 2px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "reportingservicesglyphs-regular";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 14pt;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    .glyphui-calendar:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-powerbi:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-refresh:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-back:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-firstpage:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-lastpage:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-previouspage:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-nextpage:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-downarrow:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-save:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .glyphui-print:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .MenuBarBkGnd div, .MenuBarBkGnd span, .DocMapBar {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .ActiveLink:link {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .ActiveLink:hover {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .ActiveLink:visited {
        color: #000000;
    }

        .ActiveLink:visited:hover {
            color: #000000;
        }

    :focus {
        outline-color: #F4F4F4;
    }

    span.glyphui {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .aspNetDisabled.DisabledButton span.glyphui {
        color: #7A7A7A;
    }

    .MenuBarBkGnd .HoverButton {
        background-color: #F4F4F4;
    }

    .WaitControlBackground {
        background-color: White;
        border-color: #DDDDDD;
    }

    .WaitText {
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #000000;
    }

    a, a:visited {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .CancelLinkText {
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .sk-circle .sk-child:before {
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    .spinnie .dot:after {
        background: #000000;
    }

    .ParametersFrame {
        background-color: White;
        border-color: #DDDDDD;
    }

        .ParametersFrame span.glyphui:hover {
            color: #000000;
            background-color: #F4F4F4;
        }

    .ParamEntryCell .glyphui.glyphui-downarrow {
        font-size: 8pt;
    }

    .ToolBarButtonsCell {
        border-color: #DDDDDD;
    }

    .ToolBarBackground {
        background-color: White;
    }

    .ToolbarExport.WidgetSet, .ToolbarFind.WidgetSet, .ToolbarZoom.WidgetSet, .ToolbarPageNav.WidgetSet, .ToolbarRefresh.WidgetSet, .ToolbarPrint.WidgetSet, .ToolbarBack.WidgetSet, .ToolbarPowerBI.WidgetSet {
        border-color: #DDDDDD;
    }

    .DisabledLink {
        color: #7A7A7A;
    }

        .DisabledLink:hover {
            color: #7A7A7A;
        }

    .DisabledTextBox {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .NormalButton {
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .DisabledButton {
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .ToolbarExport .MenuBarBkGnd div {
        background-color: White;
        border-color: #DDDDDD;
    }

    .ToolbarExport .MenuBarBkGnd .HoverButton {
        background-color: #F4F4F4;
    }

    .ToolbarExport .glyphui-downarrow {
        font-size: 8pt;
    }

    .SplitterNormal, .SplitterHover {
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
    }

    .DocMapFrame, .DocMapTitle {
        border-color: #DDDDDD;
    }

    .documentMapHighlighting {
        background-color: #F4F4F4;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .DocMapContentCell a {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .searchHighlighting {
        background-color: #FFC20D;
    }

    .msrs-printdialog-main {
        font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .msrs-printdialog-caption, .msrs-printdialog-list-pageorientation {
        font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .msrs-printdialog-list-pagesize {
        font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .msrs-printdialog-divbuttons {
        font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #BB2124;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .msrs-printdialog-divhighlightbutton:hover, .msrs-printdialog-divhighlightbutton:focus {
        background-color: #D31115;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .msrs-printdialog-divhighlightbutton {
        background-color: #BB2124;
        border-color: #BB2124;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .msrs-printdialog-divnonhightlightbutton:hover, .msrs-printdialog-divnonhightlightbutton:focus {
        background-color: #E6E6E6;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .msrs-printdialog-divnonhightlightbutton {
        background-color: #C8C8C8;
        border-color: #C8C8C8;
        color: #000000;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I used a .ascx (WebUserControl) and added it to the <header>, all ok!

Comment: Needs to be combined with the other answer

Answer (score 1):

The content values from an answer above got mixed up. Here are the correct values:

```
.glyphui-calendar:before {
    content: "H";
}

.glyphui-powerbi:before {
    content: "E";
}

.glyphui-refresh:before {
    content: "F";
}

.glyphui-back:before {
    content: "G";
}

.glyphui-firstpage:before {
    content: "A";
}

.glyphui-lastpage:before {
    content: "B";
}

.glyphui-previouspage:before {
    content: "C";
}

.glyphui-nextpage:before {
    content: "D";
}

.glyphui-downarrow:before {
    content: "K";
}

.glyphui-save:before {
    content: "J";
}

.glyphui-print:before {
    content: "I";
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks