# SSRS Reportviewer toolbar(print button, next button, etc) not showing colors and not coming in one line

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportviewer

I am working on an SSRS report which is displayed when i click a button. I have placed the reportviewer in a panel. On button click button panel becomes visible and the reportviewer is displayed.

report is working fine but the toolbar which contains print button,next button and so on is not showing color nor it is coming in one line.

[Toolbar from my report(no color is visible nor the contents are on one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxS34.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You may find an answer by looking at this similar, previously asked question about report viewer here:
[Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891918/ssrs-2016-report-viewer-v13-toolbar-icons-not-displaying)

Also check out the common issues section from Microsoft:

> "Common issues:
>   The viewer control is designed for modern browsers. The
>   control may not work as expected if the browser renders the page using
>   IE compatibility mode. Intranet sites may require a meta tag to
>   override default browser behavior."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017